# installing laravel under wamp

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

i am new to php world, i had learned somewhat php and mysql, decided to use some framework, 
i make choice with laravel .

i had successfully installed laravel using tutorial given in http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Laravel-Framework-in-Windows

my question is if i need to create new project in laravel again did i need to run command "composer install " , (what it actually does  i didnt understand )

please help me with this issue

**edit**

i am totally new to php framework , can i get basic help for how it works ?

Comment: Yes, just read the docs from the beginning. If you have a specific question then ask again with your code. `http://laravel.com/docs/installation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) download composer

https://getcomposer.org/download/

https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

2) install composer

> > during installation give wamp installation path.
> >         so it can composer in same php directory. for example 
> >     C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3

3) navigate to WWW directory then

open command prompt

type below command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

it will new create new directory

during this if open `ssl` error occur then

so enable below extension in `php.ini(php)`

> extension=php_openssl.dll

4) now you can access home page using below url

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new project use:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist`

Read the docs: [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/quick)